How to include nightonke in android project
I download this source code from github ,but it shows an error in nightonke can anyone please share if you know how to solve this issue .
i include nightonke and boommenu library in dependencies also but not able to resolve .i think it may include any file from outside but i doesnt know the proper procedure.
This are the library i included in dependencies

implementation ("com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.1")
implementation ("fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])")

